How can I add connection points along the length of bones?
I've been working on an armature which aims to provide realistic motion with ZERO SHAPEKEYS, and Through a combination of constraints and drivers I have come pretty close in most positions, but the more I refine those positions, the worse others become.
Just today I struck on the possibility of making a script that could alter a bone to include additional attachment points along the length of it, which I would then use for simulated 'muscle' and 'tendon' control bones, thus saving me the hassle of writing a script for each one and using dozens of Stretch-To constraints.
Trouble is I have no idea where to start. I'm reading through the API for constraints and values, and bendybones, but there's a lot in there that I don't understand. So any insights on the inner workings of the Armature system would be appreciated and help me figure out what I really need to look for.
